# "there’s more where that came from"

Tags: meaning

*That may be just the beginning of Russia’s growing presence. In addition, Iran is worried that Syria will fall to Syrian rebels backed by Saudi Arabia, Tehran’s enduring rival in the region, and so has extended a $1 billion credit line to Assad’s regime to help it import critical goods and commodities. Iran’s escape from sanctions—and its ability to earn more revenue by producing an additional one million barrels of oil per day by late next year—suggest **there’s more where that came from**.*

Source: http://time.com/4039940/these-5-facts-explain-bashar-assads-hold-in-syria/

I am not able to  figure out the meaning of the bold part of above text. Not sure which noun the pronoun "that" represents in the clause. Can you tell me what does exactly Iran’s escape from sanctions suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***There’s [plenty] more where that came from!*** is an idiomatic informal expression often used after an act of aggression, telling whoever you've just attacked that you are able and willing to continue hostilities  if the victim doesn't concede defeat (you still have more aggressive capabilities in reserve).

In the cited context, "that" refers back to the fact that Iran has lent Assad’s regime $1b. The writer is saying that since the rest of the world haven't imposed effective economic sanctions on Iran for doing this, there's every reason to suppose that they will continue to support Assad with further loans in future. They've still got plenty more money, *and* a (probably increasing) wish to keep Assad in power.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I must disagree somewhat with the distinguished Mr @FumbleFingers here. "There's more where that came from" is used in many contexts, and I think acts of aggression would be a very minor use.

I think it's more a stock phrase than an idiom. That is, the phrase means exactly what the literal words say. You (or someone) has just received or otherwise been made aware of a quantity of something. Then someone tells you, "There is more [of that thing] where that [the amount you already have] came from." That is, the source of this thing is not exhausted, there is still more available.

It's commonly used when someone gives you food. "Are you hungry? Eat as much as you like. There's more where that came from."

It is used for any "supply" of something. "I've used up all the nails you brought." "Oh, don't worry. There's more where that came from." (Sometimes, "there are more where those came from" when describing something countable.)

If someone punched me in the face and then said, "Hey, there's more where that came from," I'd understand this to mean that he is prepared to engage in further acts of violence. But I've never heard the phrase used that way. Maybe I just don't move in the same raw and violent world that @FumbleFingers does. :-)